# IIS get real client IP Address when behind a AWS Elastic load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, reverse-proxy, load-balancing, iis-7

I have a IIS server behind a AWS Elastic load balancer. I want retrieve the real client ip address set into `x-forwarded-for` header from [AWS Elastic load balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/it/elasticloadbalancing/).

I have found this setting for enable [proxy mode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity/), but IIS require the static IP address of the load balancer and the load balancer has only dynamic ip address.

```
<security>
  <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" enableProxyMode="true">
    <add ipAddress="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" allowed="true"/>
  </ipSecurity>
</security>
```

How to enable proxy mode with dynamic ip address?

Comment: Why does the distinction between trusting `x-forwarded-for` and assuming direct connections matter? (Why is your upstream reachable for anyone *other* than the load balancer?)

Comment: @anx mhh, what happen if user send a "x-forwarded-for" with curl?